# How to see the miner account that earned gas? Or how to know the account where gas goes?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, gas, mining

I made a transaction to another account on rinkeby and then saw the record on Etherscan. There is Txn fee as gas. But how can I know where the gas went. I mean the account that gas was paid to. I think there should be a miner account that receives the gas. Is there any way to know the miner's account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Once the transaction is mined, click on the block number you can see in the tx details to access the block details. The address of the miner is indicated in "Mined by".